# How to have a client (e.g browser) that request some resource over UDP and other over TCP using python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I understand that HTTP works over TCP.  I am trying to send some sources from python server to client over UDP and some other resources over TCP.

Is it possible to have a client (e.g browser) that request some resource over UDP and other over TCP using python?
Any idea on how I can approach this. Possibly using python socket programming.

Comment: If you want to use UDP from the browser, the short answer is no, you can’t do it

Comment: @Voldmar, thanks, what about using a proxy that requests and receives over UDP before sending it to the browser over TCP?

Comment: I suppose you may write it in Python. In any case it’s a big chance you will need to implement this UDP protocol